# Retrieving Hive Table Location using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

Is there a way to retrieve hdfs location of a hive table using 
Java jdbc.

For example:

I have a temporary table t1. 
at location '/user/tables_list/t1';

I want to retrieve this location using java code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've tried, there isn't a direct way to do this. But, once you've set up your JDBC connection you can execute a "DESCRIBE EXTENDED ", which (in the test I did) will list the table columns for:

```
res = stmt.executeQuery("DESCRIBE EXTENDED tweets");
while(res.next()){
    System.out.println(res.getString(1));
}
```

but, for the last row, you'll need to use:

```
res.getString(2)
```

which will give you a detailed table description that you'll need to parse, but somewhere in there there's a a location field

```
location:hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/social.db/tweets
```

The problem with this, is that is a lot of handwork, because methods like:

```
res.last()
```

or

```
res.isLast()
```

are not supported, and they would be of a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and I used HiveMetaStoreClient API and it makes it as easy as typing:

```
srcTable.getSd().getLocation();
```

srcTable should be the table object which is retrieved from Hive metastore by giving the table specifications.